# Microsoft Power Pages - Dynamic filtering between two lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, powerapps

Is it possible to filter:
I have an A list and a B list on one power pages. I select record A list and in list B only records related by one-to-many relationship are shown to me.

[Power Pages javascipt](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/power-pages/configure/add-custom-javascript-list)

I need filtering between lists linked by a one-to-many relationship depending on the user action.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.